# Can iPhone 6 tell if a surface is horizontal?

Tags: iphone, ios, compass

I can launch the Compass app on my iPhone 4 and it can tell if the surface I'm placing it on is perfectly horizontal, or it's bending to any direction. Given iPhone 6's sticking-out camera, can it still measure such things?

Comment: You'll have to either leave the camera out of the plane to be measured or put the phone inside a case or cover that solves this issue.

Comment: Find a surface that your iPhone 4 says is level, then see what an iPhone 6 says about it.

Comment: @user24601 I asked a coworker to make a test; his phone said -1 degrees where my said 0. So the camera is not making much difference. After putting the case back on his phone it also detected 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Find a surface that you trust to to be level
2. Open the compass/spirit level app and place phone on it
3. Tap the screen while phone is placed on the surface - this will recalibrate the accelerometer reading on your iphone6 implicitly
   taking into account the camera bump as well.
4. Go measure the things you want to measure :)

There is a catch to this, as it does assume that the surface is wide enough to place an iPhone 6 down *with* the camera bump touching the surface.